# Where is memory allocated for a T-SQL variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

In T-SQL, when we do something like

```
declare @PolicyId int = 20
```

4 bytes are allocated, since the size of an `int` is 4 bytes, but *where* is this memory allocated - is it on the stack or the heap?

Comment: And the reason you need to know is...?

Comment: I was reviwing a stored procdeure, wheares inside a while loop a varaible was declare, I was wondering what this will invite, garbage collection(heap) or stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe you should worry more about eliminating the loop than figuring out what exact type of exception will happen when it craps the bed.

Comment: It may depend on the context of the declaration, e.g. in a stored procedure or a loop, and the data type, e.g. `INT` rather than `TABLE`.

Comment: @user92546 int will go on stack and table on heap?????

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand loop seems inavitable in scenario i have...

Comment: @Pritesh I don't believe that. Almost every loop in T-SQL can be changed to a set-based operation with no loop. Sometimes it's better to leave it in a loop, but that is rare (running totals is one case where, before SQL Server 2012, a cursor outperforms the purist set-based solutions). If you're worried about your loop blowing up your server, might be worth considering instead of throwing your hands in the air and believing the loop is necessary.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand in the loop I have some condtional insert and calll to 4-5 Stored procedure. how can i convert it to SET based???

Comment: Not something I can address in a vague comment. Depends on what the 4-5 stored procedures are doing, doesn't it?

Comment: **Loops are never `inavitable`**

Answer (score 7):

T-SQL variables are not on the stack nor on the heap. They are named logical entities in the current execution context. Placing a declare inside a loop is the same as placing it outside the loop. You will not cause a memory exhaustion nor stack overflow by placing variables inside a loop. See the following code:

```
declare @i int =0
while @i<2
begin
    declare @x int = 0;
    set @x += 1
    print @x;
    set @i += 1;
end

print @x;
```

Notice how the `@x` can be referenced outside the loop, even though is declared inside the loop. Ie. the loop did *not* create a scope. But the initial assignment *does* get executed in every iteration of the loop (the value printed is always `1`, not `1,2,3...`).